# Regex uppercase

Tags: regex

I have a list of strings like this:

```
purpcl ("purpose clause modifier"),
quantmod ("quantier modifier"),
rcmod ("relative clause modifier"),
```

Is it possible to make them like this:

```
PURPCL ("purpose clause modifier"),
QUANTMOD ("quantier modifier"),
RCMOD ("relative clause modifier"),
```

Comment: You can't do it in plain regex. What language are you using?

Comment: Hmm. But that's not uppercase-ing all of it. See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Changing_case_with_regular_expressions

Comment: @dmedvinsky - I'm trying to do a find and replace thing in my IDE, Netbeans. I was just wondering if I could do it in plain regex instead of writing program to do it for me.

Comment: PERL supports this kind of thing, but simply using the IDE won't cut it I think.

Comment: @Adel that's not really regex, that's vim patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with some tools, such as `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^(]+)/\U\1/'
purpcl ("purpuse clause modifier"),
PURPCL ("purpuse clause modifier"),
```

But you should definitely not use regular expressions for this kind of processing.

Comment: Why shouldn't he use regexp for that? For making code changes in an IDE, where one can have a quick look before every replace-find-next if that is really the desired change?

Answer (score 0):

Some languages (like Perl) and/or editors (or IDE's) have such features, but in general, no, that is not possible with regex alone.

And only changing the letter that are outside of string literals is already stretching the capabilities of regex.